# Is my name on spouse’s passport sufficient to prove relation & bring her to Saudi Arabia on family visit visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, saudi-arabia

I want to clear my doubt. Is it mandatory to provide a marriage certificate while bringing a spouse to Saudi Arabia when her passport has my name mentioned on it?

Comment: Please state the citizenship of you both, and country of residence if different.

Answer (score 3):

You must provide a copy of the marriage certificate/contract to obtain a spouse visit visa.

Source: The guy who is responsible about helping employees obtain visas in my multi-national company in Saudi Arabia.